# How to return true or false values using JavaScript or jQuery after click on confirm or cancel button from confirm box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on one project in that if user try to refresh current page they will get confirm box with alert `Don't refresh page or else you will lose data` so if they cancel then he will stay on same page, but my problem is when they click on yes i.e Reload as he click reload one more alert should get `you clicked reload now page will reload and data will loss`, so how to do this because I am not getting any thing when he click on Reload button.

below I have  written script.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ 
        return prompt("are you sure want to refresh this page !");

        if(true){
            alert('You will lose data');
        }
        else{
            alert("Ok continue your work");
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "You will loose data"...should be "lose". "loose" means something else. Just a small thing to make your app look more professional. And the ! in "are you sure want to refresh this page !" should be a ?, and there shouldn't be a space before it. the "a" in "are" should also be capitalised ("Are") because it's the start of a sentence. Maybe if you are not a native English speaker you should ask someone to check your grammar and spelling. The wording of your question also lacks adequate punctuation and is difficult to follow.

Comment: You are doing `return prompt()` any code after a `return` statement will not be executed

Comment: @PatrickEvans ok please tell me how to solve issue even if i remove return still not getting anything.

Answer (score 1):

A `return` statement exit a function so everything after a return statement is not executed

I don't think you want a `prompt` box but a `confirm` box (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)).

- A `prompt` box is used only to get something by the user
- A `confirm` box is used to ask the user if he confirms something

```js
var rep = confirm("are you sure want to refresh this page !");
console.log(rep);

if(rep){
  alert('You will lose data');
}
else{
  alert("Ok continue your work");
}
```

Comment: i want this should work when user try to refresh for that purpose i have mentioned onbeforeload in script

Comment: This will, just put the code i gave you in your `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){`

Comment: just now i tried that whatever you mentioned   still without any confirm box or alert directly refreshing page.

Comment: Browsers may block alerts, confirms and prompts inside the  'beforeunload' event in order to avoid annoying pop-ups.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about but without further information by the SO I cannot help more than with this answer

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do not use Jquery when using onBeforeLoad event. It causing unwanted behavior. 
Vanilla JS would handle it better.

example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function beforeExit();

function beforeExit(){
return confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?");
}
```

with this method, your function will execute if the user is trying to refresh the page.

Comment: it is not working can you please send me working code for this.

Comment: not getting expected output I mean not getting alert please check at your system if it works tell me what changes i have to do

Comment: @Anonymous, try with a `console.log()`. Alert might get blocked.